# Laravel Passport: Extending the Token's life time

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, passport-jwt

**Question:**
I would like to ask how I can **extend** token's lifetime. *As long* as the user uses the application and when the user does not perform any activity on the application for one hour, for example, the token is terminated?

## **Example**:

The user login, then a token with lifetime for one hour is generated here

## A:

As long as the user responds with the app, the lifespan of this token is extended. (So tokenLieftime = now + 1hour).

## B:

The user has no reaction with the app for an hour, then the token is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a middleware to refresh the token and return it to user in every request. Also make sure that you set the lifespan of your refresh token to 1 hour too. Cheers ;)